# Is it not possible to run --zmq-pub with the --rpc-restricted parameter?

Tags: mining-pools

I have tried different combinations and it looks like --zmq-pub for p2pool can only be pointed to a monerod that is ran regular with bounded port on 18081.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use the restricted rpc parameter on the monerod but you have to make sure to allow the regular rpc by calling it like --rpc-bind-port/ip.

p2pool only connects to 18081 it can't use 18089.